# Bit-wise left shifting a value into a dynamically allocated memory pointed by void*

Tags: c, void-pointers, libvirt

I am trying to create a CPU-Map for a Libvirt API function. The idea is depending on the number of physical CPUs, I allocate memory of 1, 2 or 4 bytes (supporting upto 32 CPUs). For example if a platform has 16 CPUs, I allocate 2 bytes.

After memory allocation, I need to set the set the CPU bit. For example: If I have 16 CPUs in the platform and I want to pin a Virtual CPU to the 16th CPU, I need to set the MSB in the memory allocated. See the code snippet below.

```
void *cpuMap;

switch (pCpus/8) {
case 0:
case 1:
    size = sizeof(unsigned char);
    cpuMap = (unsigned char*) malloc(size);
    break;
case 2:
    size = sizeof(unsigned short int);
    cpuMap = (unsigned short int*) malloc(size);
    break;
case 3:
case 4:
default:
    size = sizeof(unsigned int);
    cpuMap = (unsigned int*) malloc(size);
    break;
}

*cpuMap = 0x1 << cpu_number; //error: invalid use of void expression
```

I get the below error during compilation

```
vcpu_scheduler.c:317:3: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
  317 |   *cpuMap = 0x1 << cpu_number;
      |   ^~~~~~~
vcpu_scheduler.c:317:11: error: invalid use of void expression
  317 |   *cpuMap = 0x1 << cpu_number;
      |           ^
make: *** [Makefile:4: compile] Error 1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Casting the result of `malloc` doesn't change what happens when it gets dereferenced, C isn't dynamically typed. You need to do the assignment when you know what type you're trying to use.

Comment: `pCpus` and `cpu_number`  hmmm... same or different things?

Comment: `pCpus` equal 12 --> case 1 Hmmm... is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off just always using `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t`) and just allocating mulitple bytes (and indexing) when you need more than one:

```
unsigned char *cpuMap;

cpuMap = malloc((pCpus + 7U)/8U);  // round up to a mulitple of 8
memset(cpuMap, 0, (pCpus + 7U)/8U);

cpuMap[cpu_number / 8U] |= 1U << (cpu_number % 8U);
```

Comment: For sure a much nicer solution... and it can be used even if OP should insist on `cpuMap` being a void-pointer

Comment: I do not see any reason to malloc <=4 bytes of memory and store its reference in the 8 bytes long(on 64 bits machine) pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deference `void*` because it is a incomplete type that cannot be completed by design. One must cast it to an appropriate type assign the right value.

For example:

```
case 2:
    size = sizeof(unsigned short int);
    cpuMap = malloc(size);
    *(unsigned short int*)cpuMap = 0x1 << cpu_number;
    break;
```

add similar code for other cases.

Note that after setting `cpuMap` can only be accessed by the type used to initialize it (+ few exception) to avoid violating strict aliasing rule.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to allocate 1 or 2 bytes. Always allocate 4 bytes. Allocating less will not save you any memory, but instead will complicate the code for no reason.

Also using dynamic memory allocation for 4 bytes of memory makes no (or a very, very little) sense. The pointer where you store its reference will be twice in size on 64 bits machine :)

To be sure how many bits the type has, use fixed-size integers from *standard*

```
uint32_t cpumap = 0;

/* ... */

cpumap |= 0x1UL << cpu_number;
```

Comment: I agree that OPs approach is rather strange but this doesn't answer what OP asked

Comment: @4386427 IMO he simple overthought it and his approach makes no sense so I have proposed a bit more logical solution

Answer (score 0):

Using `void *` breaks type safety. Better to use a single type (e.g.) `uint8_t` -- using `uint8_t/uint16_t/uint32_t` depending on number of CPUs provides little advantage speedwise and makes the code more complex.

We have to round up the number of CPUs to get the number of bytes.

No real need to use `malloc`. Just use a fixed size based on maximum possible CPUs (e.g. 32, 64, 128, 256). For your [maximum] use case of 32 CPUs, using four bytes all the time isn't a real issue as to the size of the vector.

---

When I do bit vectors, I prefer to use macros/functions to isolate the operations.

Here are some macros I've used in the past:

```
// btv.h -- bit vector primitives

// NOTE: by using 0x80, we are compatible with perl's vec function

typedef unsigned char btv_t;

// number of bytes for vector
#define BTVSIZE(_bit) \
    (((_bit) + 7) >> 3)

// index/offset into bit vector
#define BTVOFF(_bit) \
    ((_bit) >> 3)

// bit vector bit mask
#define BTVMSK(_bit) \
    (0x80 >> ((_bit) >> 3))

// bit vector byte pointer
#define BTVPTR(_sym,_bit) \
    (((btv_t *) _sym) + BTVOFF(_bit))

// set bit in vector
#define BTVSET(_sym,_bit) \
    *BTVPTR(_sym,_bit) |= BTVMSK(_bit)

// clear bit in vector
#define BTVCLR(_sym,_bit) \
    *BTVPTR(_sym,_bit) &= ~BTVMSK(_bit)

// test bit in vector
#define BTVTST(_sym,_bit) \
    (*BTVPTR(_sym,_bit) & BTVMSK(_bit))

// set/clear bit in vector
#define BTVFLG(_sym,_bit,_set) \
    do { \
        btv_t *__btvptr__ = BTVPTR(_sym,_bit); \
        btv_t __btvmsk__ = BTVMSK(_bit); \
        if (_set) \
            *__btvptr__ |= __btvmsk__; \
        else \
            *__btvptr__ &= ~__btvmsk__; \
    } while (0)
```

---

Here's a wrapper for functions for use with cpus:

```
// cpumap.c -- CPU mask primitives

#include "btv.h"

// pick whatever maximum number of CPUs you want ...
#define CPUMAX          256

typedef btv_t cpumap_t[BTVSIZE(CPUMAX)];

void
cpumapset(cpumap_t map,unsigned int cpuno)
{

    BTVSET(map,cpuno);
}

void
cpumapclr(cpumap_t map,unsigned int cpuno)
{

    BTVCLR(map,cpuno);
}

btv_t
cpumaptst(cpumap_t map,unsigned int cpuno)
{

    return BTVTST(map,cpuno);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The libvirt API provides macros that are intended for use with the pinning APIs to make this simpler:

```
unsigned char *cpuMap = malloc(VIR_CPU_MAPLEN(pCpus));
VIR_USE_CPU(cpuMap, cpu_number);
```